# Reverse pystache

Tags: python, mustache

I have this script:

```
import pystache
template = 'Hi {{person}}!'
data = {'person': 'Mom'}
txt = pystache.render(template, data)
print txt
```

Which gives:

```
Hi Mom!
```

Is there a way of doing something like:

```
data = reverse_pystache(txt, template)
```

So that a dictionary is returned:

```
>>> data
{'person': 'Mom'}
```

That is, reusing the template which was used to generate the text, and the actual text, extract the data from the text.

Comment: Did you find something about this subject?

Comment: This is a long time ago, but I think I was not able to solve that problem